# how to get 2 values from a nested Json string with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I m using jackson library to deserialize from Json. I need to extract only 2 value from this json i.e. c1 and d1. I have used this code... I need to know the correct approach to overcome get c1 and d1 values...

My json

```
{"Alpha":{"A":{"B":{"C":{"c1":1234,c2:"abcd"},"D":{"d1":"xyz","d2":5678,"d3":"qwerty"},"E":[{"e1":456,"e2":"mnop"},{"e1":098,"e2":"qrst"}]}}},"X"{"x1":8098}}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mainclass alphaobj = mapper.readValue(new File("C:\\employee.json"), mainclass.class);
System.out.println(alphaobj.A.B.C.getc1());
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying 'overcome get c1 and d1 values'? Also please show your `mainclass` definition.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use Jackson [Tree Model](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel) instead?

Something like:

```
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(file);
int c1 = root.path("Alpha").path("A").path("C").path("C1").intValue();
```

and so on.

Comment: thanks for the idea. but i am planning to use bean and parse each json into a bean and read the value.

Comment: I guess I don't know what exactly is your problem: what you are doing is correct, assuming you have defined getters mentioned in beans?